# Capturing text output to a log, while printing REALTIME to terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, printing, scripts, tee

My output prints approximately 1 line per second to the terminal, maybe 100-200 lines in total.

I've tried to capture the output using `tee`, but it prints all the lines at the end of the process, not in realtime.

I also tried using the `script` command, but the output file had some weird characters such as `^M` printed along with the results, which is no good.

How can I print in realtime while capturing!?

Comment: While the question is not very clear.. like what is ouput where are you capturing.. but `watch` may serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the output buffer behaviour of your program with something like [`stdbuf(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/de/man1/stdbuf.1.html):

```
stdbuf -oL brasteins-program | tee brasteins-program.log
```

Comment: My bad, thought I read HSU, not HU in Berlin. Oh well, cheers anyway.